# Save changes in Excel Worksheet DataSet

Tags: c#, excel, dataset, ribbon, tableadapter

I'm making custom Excel workbook in Visual Studio with custom Ribbon. I am using DataSet to connect to SQL Server database. 
Column:

```
ID|Chance|CustomerDate|ProviderDate|
 1|     0|  2014-02-11|  2014-02-27|
 2|     5|  2014-03-11|  2014-03-20|
 3|    15|  2014-04-11|  2014-04-15|
```

From custom ribbon I open new wpf window where I can add some rows to data set and save it using this code:

```
Try
{
   this.MyDataSet_AnalisysTableAdapter.Update(this.MyDataSet.Analisys);
}
Catch(Exception)
{
   throw;
}
```

And it works very good.

Next: Using the same DataSet I've added view to Excel worksheet (simply by dragging Table from Data Sources into worksheet). All data are listed properly.

When I change `chance` on some row, and save it with the same code as above (of course implemented in Worksheet1.cs) there is no effect in database. Although when I open custom wpf window I can see changes in related tableView, and when I use save method from this window everything is saving as it should...

I need to have opportunity to save change made in worksheet (from worksheet) as well as in this window. So my question is: How can I save changes from Worksheet?

Comment: It's just short sample of my code. If you don't want to write anything useful then don't write at all...

Comment: Again, nothing constructive... Read question again and try to understand what it is about. Thank you.